# Asp.Net Core Web API - Error CS0747 Invalid initializer member declarator

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this code in ASP.NET Core Web API:

DTO:

```
public class AuthRequest
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class AuthResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Services:

```
public interface IAuthService
{
    Task<AuthResponse> Login(AuthRequest request);
}

public async Task<AuthResponse> Login(AuthRequest request)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"User with {request.Email} not found.");
    }

    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, request.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Credentials for '{request.Email} aren't valid'.");
    }

    JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken = await GenerateToken(user);
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

    AuthResponse response = new AuthResponse
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken),
        Email = user.Email,
        UserName = user.UserName,
        roles,
    };

    return response;
}
```

From the code above, I want to include roles of the logged in user in the AuthResponse. So I added, **roles**

But I got this error:

> Error CS0747 Invalid initializer member declarator

roles is highlighted.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... did you added the Roles property in the AuthResponse model class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how this property initialization:

```
roles,
```

differs from the rest:

```
Id = user.Id,
Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken),
Email = user.Email,
UserName = user.UserName,
```

You need to specify *which property* is being set.  For example, is there a `Roles` property (which matches the type)?  If so, it would be something like this:

```
Roles = roles,
```

Basically, whatever property you're trying to initialize in the resulting object, you need to indicate the name of that property in its initialization.